# Visual Studio Code : "invalid syntax" popping up when i have checked it 3 times

Tags: python

Why I try to run my discord bot, I get an "invalid syntax" error.

This is what it says:

```
>>> & "C:/Users/NAME/anaconda3/python.exe" "c:/Users/NAME/Desktop/Discord bot/Disc bot/disc bot.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & "C:/Users/NAME/anaconda3/python.exe" "c:/Users/NAME/Desktop/Discord bot/Disc bot/disc bot.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are on the Python prompt not on the system shell.

Comment: How do I get to the shell?

Comment: To get to the shell type `exit()` at the Python `>>>` prompt.

Comment: @Charalamm 

import discord